# Matlab - setting breakpoints in called functions

Tags: matlab, debugging

When I used older versions of MATLAB, I used to place breakpoints in any function that was called from the script/function I was running.

I've now moved to Matlab 2013, an now if I set a breakpoint inside a function that's called from my script, this breakpoint is ignored and disappears after the run - I must put a breakpoint in the call to the function in the script I'm executing, then step in, and then I can set breakpoints in the function I'm debugging. I know for sure that Matlab does executes the line I'm setting the breakpoint at (used debug prints).

Is there a way to change the preferences so that I could set the breakpoints not only in the executed script?

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but a "clear all" command at the top of your script would cause this behaviour.

Comment: Somehow after more than 3 years of usage I had no idea... Thanks a bunch!